# nuxtServerInit and API Requests

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and I'm using `Firebase` as an API. I'm using `nuxtServerInit` to fetch all of my products from the firebase API. I only have 3 categories and around 20 products so the API request is very small.

So that means I'm getting all of my products in one go, I'm then dispatching the products and putting them into my store.

I just wanted to ask before I start fully building the application right out if this is the right way to go about this?

- Using `nuxtServerInit` to fetch all products and the whole API in 1 call
- Storing the products list into the store
- Subsequent product detail pages I'm using `_lodash` `_.get(params.id)` or `_.find(params.id)` to find the details of the products rather than another call with Axios.

So Essentially fetching from the API than using the store for all other access rather than async data via Axios on all other pages?

**Routes** 
My routes are all dynamic

- Products (Lists all products)
- Category (eg t-shrits)
- Detail (details of the shirt)

**nuxtServerInit**

```
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit(context){
        return axios.get(URL+'/products.json')
        .then(response => {
            context.dispatch('products/getProducts', response.data)
        })
        .catch(e => context.error(e));
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which routes you are maintaining?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I would recommend making an API call on specific routes to firebase inside `asyncData` or `fetch` method than store data into `VueX` and access it

Comment: Ok thanks....can you give reasons for this? I thought because I have a small API that I could just get the products from the store each time rather than hitting API endpoints each time. I've managed to access the data quite easily for dynamic routes

Comment: IMO Nothing is small on web! Only ask that much data from API that will require for the page.  And then if data will not going to change frequently you can store it at browser level or with `Vuex-persist`. I hope I have answered your question!

Comment: Ok thanks....that was kind of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Nuxt.js documentaion](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action):

> If the action `nuxtServerInit` is defined in the store and the mode is
>   universal, Nuxt.js will call it with the context (only from the
>   server-side). It's useful when we have some data on the server we want
>   to give directly to the client-side.

If you have small amount of data (3 categories and around 20 products) and you want to use that data directly on the client, I think it's perfectly fine to store it in the state. Because, this will help you avoid additional API calls during navigation.

`nuxtServerInit` will fill the store on the first page load. And you don't need to worry about any API requests anymore. I think this also will give you performance boost and responsiveness.

The last but not the least, [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) is only available within pages (*not in components*) but [`fetch`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) can be called from any of your Vue components.

Comment: Great thanks...Also I changed some data in firebase then refreshed the page and the page updated so the nuxtServerInit must have went to the API again. Does it know when the data has changed somehow or does nuxtServerInit fire again between routes?

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` will not fire between routes and page refresh is needed when your data changes. You may want to consider using `fetch` method if you have a data that frequently changes.

Comment: upvoted! more important question is does nuxtserverinit block? meaning will the page not be rendered fast if your api has lots of data, think an array of 5000 items where each item is a string of 8 letters

Comment: @PirateApp I think it's optional. If you define it as an async action, nuxt server will wait until it finishes ([source](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action)).